# Extract text from HTML with Javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to parse a webpage and to get the number reference after <li>YM#. For example I need to get 1234-234234 in a variable from the HTML that contains

<li>YM# 1234-234234         </li>

Many thanks for your help someone!

Rich

Comment: var text = document.body.innerHTML;
    console.log(text);
    text = text.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,'');
    var id = text.match(/YM#[0-9]-[0-9]/g);

I know I am a way off!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

currently, your regex only matches if there is a single number before the dash and a single number after it. This will let you get one or more numbers in each place instead:

```
/YM#[0-9]+-[0-9]+/g
```

Then, you also need to capture it, so we use a cgroup to captue it:

```
/YM#([0-9]+-[0-9]+)/g
```

Then we need to refer to the capture group again, so we use the following code instead of the String.match

```
var regex = /YM#([0-9]+-[0-9]+)/g;
var match = regex.exec(text);
var id = match[1];
 // 0: match of entire regex
 // after that, each of the groups gets a number
```

Comment: Thankyou for telling me exactly how to do it. It didn't actually work initially but it was so close I managed to fix it myself. It needed \s in between # and [ as there is a space. Thanks so much Jasper!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
`(<li>[^#<>]*?# *)([\d\-]+)\b`
and get the result in `$2`.

Comment: Try: ``result = subject.replace(/(<li>[^#<>]*?# *)([\d]+)\b/g, "$2");``

Answer (score 1):

`(?!<li>YM#\s)([\d-]+)`

http://regexr.com?30ng5

This will match the numbers.